# Is it safe to have the TCP port 2376 open by docker-machine (generic driver) to the internet?

Tags: security, docker, docker-machine

I'm experimenting with Docker Machine, trying to set it up on an already existing machine using `docker-machine create --driver generic`. I noticed that it reconfigures the firewall so that port 2376 is open to the Internet. Does it also set up proper authentication, or is there a risk that I'm exposing root access to this machine as a side effect?

Answer (score 3):

By default, docker-machine configures mutual TLS (mTLS) to both encrypt the communication, and verify the client certificate to limit access. From the [docker-machine documentation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/create/#specifying-configuration-options-for-the-created-docker-engine):

> As part of the process of creation, Docker Machine installs Docker and configures it with some sensible defaults. For instance, it allows connection from the outside world over TCP with TLS-based encryption and defaults to AUFS as the storage driver when available.

You should see environment variables configured by docker-machine for the DOCKER_HOST and DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY to point to a remote host and use mTLS certificates. Typically, port 2375 is an unencrypted and unsecured port that should never be used, and 2376 is configured with at least TLS, and hopefully mTLS (without the mutual part to verify clients, security is non existent). For more details on what it takes to configure this, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

All that being said, docker with mTLS is roughly the same security as SSH with only key pair logins allowed. Considering the access it grants to the host, I personally don't leave either of these exposed to the internet despite being fairly secure. When possible, I use IP whitelists, VPNs, or other measures to limit access. But many may feel relatively safe leaving these ports exposed.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using certificates to secure the socket, it's prone for attacks. See more info [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/).

In the past, some of my test cloud instances were compromised and turned into bitcoin miners. In one instance, since there were keys available on that particular host, the attacker could use those keys to create new cloud instances.